# Python: Pass class member item to one of its member functions by reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, pass-by-reference

I have a some functions inside a class that operate on the class members. These functions are almost identical apart from the class member they operate on. To avoid having to type out the function over and over again, only changing the class member that is changed, I have created a function where one of the parameters is the class member to change.

Here is a very simplified version:

```
class Foo:
    a = 0
    b = 0

    def __set_member(self, member, value):
        member = value

    def set_a(self, value):
        self.__set_member(self.a, value)

f = Foo()

print(f.a)
f.set_a(2)
print(f.a)
```

But this outputs:

```
0
0
```

in C++ this could be done with:

```
class Foo {

    void set_member(int& member, int value) {
        member = value;
    }

public:
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    void set_a(int value) {
        set_member(this->a, value);
    }
};
```

Obviously the example I have given doesn't require the `set_member` function because it is so simple.

In my actual code, the setter looks something like this:

```
def requestOpenDoor1(self):
    # Non blocking function: sets door1 to `Opening` and then after 2 seconds sets it to `Open`
    self.__door1 = DoorStates.Opening
    async def callback(): self.__door1 = DoorStates.Open
    self.__tasks.append(AsyncTimer(2, callback))
```

One approach is to copy and paste this function 20 or so times and just change the class member that is being modified, transition State, time, and endState, but I would rather reduce duplication of code.

I have also tried to use decorators to solve this problem:

```
class request_function_decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, tasks, stateToChange, transitionState, time, endState):
        self.__tasks = tasks
        self.__stateToChange = stateToChange
        self.__transitionState = transitionState
        self.__time = time
        self.__endState = endState
    def __call__(self, function):
        def wrapped_f(*args):
            self.__stateToChange = self.__transitionState
            async def callback(): self.__stateToChange = self.__endState
            self.__tasks.append(AsyncTimer(self.__time, callback))
        return wrapped_f

@request_function_decorator(__tasks, __door1, States.Opening, 2, States.Open)
def requestOpenDoor1(self):
    pass
```

But this also doesn't work.

How can generalize this function to reduce duplication of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=setattr#object.__setattr__)?

Comment: Are you sure you actually *want* class attributes? I suspect `a` and `b` are supposed to be *instance* attributes, which you can set directly without any setter boilerplate. (If you *do* find you need setters later, you can define properties.)

Comment: You can also get a pointer-like effect with class members that are lists. It's like having a pointer that you dereference using its index. I posted an answer demonstrating this.

Comment: I kindly but very strongly suggest you 1/ do the [full Python official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), 2/ read the [doc on Python's data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and finally 3/ read this [very good article about python's names and bindings](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Python is totally different from C++, so you can't expect to just write C++ code in Python ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should have [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=setattr#object.__setattr__) by default:

```py
class Foo:
    a = 0
    b = 0

f = Foo()
print(f.a)
# 0

f.a = 9
print(f.a)
# 9

f.__setattr__("a", 99)
print(f.a)
# 99

setattr(f, "a", 900)
print(f.a)
# 900
```

Answer (score 0):

The Python equivalent of your first snippet is quite simply this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # instances attributes must be defined on the instance, 
        # not on the class.
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def set_a(self, a):
        setattr(self, "a", a)

f = Foo()

print(f.a)
f.set_a(2)
print(f.a)
```

Now note that here `set_a` is - from a pythonic point of view - a complete WTF: first it's totally useless (`a` is a public attribute, you can set it directly), then it's implementation uses `setattr` for no good reason (you could just implement it as `self.a = a`.

FWIW, you'll very seldom find explicit setters / getters in Python. Python has a strong support for computed attributes, so if you intend to publicly expose an attribute (which is the goal and effect of getters/setters), you start with a plain attribute, and if and when the needs to control access to it arises, you just turn it into a computed one, ie:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # instances attributes must be defined on the instance, 
        # not on the class.
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter 
    def a(self, a):
        if a == 42:
            raise HitchikerError("yes, but what is the question ?")  
        self._a = a
```

Also note that the canonical naming convention for implementation attributes (attributes that are not part of the class public interface) is one single leading underscore. The double-leading underscore things (and the name-manling system it triggers) is intended only as a protection against accidental name clashes in deep inheritance hierarchies, and in is in practice almost never used (because almost ever needed).

Hope that helps...

Answer (score -1):

You can get a pointer-like effect by making the class variables mutable list objects.

Apparently, someone doesn't like my example here. What I'm demonstrating here shouldn't be required in typical code; however, coming from a C/C++ background it might make some sense. It shows an analogous case where thinking in terms of pointers has similarity to referencing a list by index and passing it to methods and functions.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     _a = [0]   # Class vars.
...     _b = [0]
...     
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._c = [0]  # Instance var.
... 
...     def _set_member(self, member, value): 
...         # Some lengthy algorithm you don't want to 
...         # implement separately for each data member...
...         member[0] = value
... 
...     @property
...     def a(self):
...         return self._a[0]
...         
...     @a.setter
...     def a(self, value):
...         self._set_member(self._a, value)
...         
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a
0
>>> f.a = 22
>>> f.a
22
>>>
```

C pointers can similarly be dereferenced using zero index. `int *a;` ...`a[0] = 1;`.

Once while implementing an interface to native library using the Python C API I needed to write wrappers for several functions that took more than one pointer as a parameter. I wanted to keep the Python facing functions parameter lists close to the C functions. So I used lists for those parameters to mimic the pointer effect.